# Best php shopping cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, cart

Been out of the game (not built a shop in years) and looked at the two old front runners (oscommerce and zcart) and neither seem to have have improved much over the years. What I am looking for is a open source cart which runs on php and connects to paypal.

What is the new cart everone is using?

R.

Comment: What constitutes "the best" shopping cart?

Comment: "Best" is in the eye of the beholder ;-) If you only want it to be that simple, then you may consider writing your own? There is a good tutorial here - Paypal integration isn't much more work http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/

Comment: open cart ( http://www.opencart.com/ ) quite good. Also the one thats really popular these days is magento ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/ ) magento has a very active community, who constantly build addons and plugins for it....hope this helps.

Comment: Wrong place to ask this. Go here for example: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest opencart (http://www.opencart.com/) and Magento (http://www.magentocommerce.com).

Both are quite solid and reliable, been using them myself. Both are quite easy to setup. Magento has, as mentioned as well in this question, a very active community so getting help is easy, and there's a lot of good plugins for them. Both work with paypal.

Comment: Avoid magento at all costs. It's a black hole that eats your soul. Worst architecture ever. (Why yes, I did spend 6 months working on a custom Magento site)

Comment: Both are quite solid and reliable, been using them myself. Both are quite easy to setup. Magento has, as mentioned as well in this question, a very active community so getting help is easy, and there's a lot of good plugins for them. Both work with paypal.

Comment: To anyone considering Magento; I have 2 years in Magento dev: Magento is great for admin users and a nightmare for developers. If you are considering developing a Mage site you will NEED a solid understanding of the Zend framework; Wordpress/PHP hacking skills will NOT CUT IT. Also, be ready to pay for *everything*. The shopping cart might be free, but the plugins you need to extend it into something useful -- 3rd party payment gateways, gift certificates, order management, etc -- will cost anywhere from $20 - $500 each. Also, plugin support is notoriously poor with many vendors.

Answer (score 0):

my last job with e-commerce
was made using http://www.zen-cart.com/
the templates are easy to integrate
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Magento seems to be the adopted free eCommerce software now days.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/